# Show that for $n∈N$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that $P(|X_n|>R)<\epsilon$.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of random variable, taking value from ($-\infty,\infty$). Show that for $n∈N$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists $R>0$  such that $P(|X_n|>R)<\epsilon$.

I mean, intuitively it is true since the value of $X_n$ is finite. We can just let $R$ be large enough and then $P(|X_n|>R)<\epsilon$.

But I do not know how to officially prove it. Anyone could help me on it?

Comment: $\{\vert X_n\vert=+\infty\}$ is of probability 0, and is the intersection of $(\{\vert X_n\vert>R\})_{R>0}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not really depend on $n$, so let's drop it, and you don't really need a random variable either, just consider any probability measure $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Use continuity of measures (from below), see e.g. [wikipedia (scroll down to basic properties)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)):
Define closed balls $B_{k} = [-k,k]$ of radius $k\in\mathbb{N}$ centered in zero to obtain:

$$
1 = P(\mathbb{R}) = P\bigg(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_{k}\bigg)
=
\lim_{k\to\infty} P(B_{k})
=
\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} P(B_{k}).
$$
By definition of the supremum, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $k^{\ast}$ such that $P(B_{k^{\ast}}) > 1-\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show for $R$ large enough, $$\epsilon>P(|X_n|>R)=1-P(|X_n|\leq R)=1-F_{|X_n|}(R)\iff F_{|X_n|}(R)>1-\epsilon,$$

where $F_{|X_n|}$ is the CDF of $|X_n|.$ By [properties of CDFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties), the limit of a CDF is $1$ as its argument tends to $+\infty$, so the desired result follows immediately.